# How can we remove duplicate line without sorting?

Tags: linux

I want to remove duplicate lines without sorting lines. Also I want to ignore leading white space.

cat test.txt

```
 abc 

  def

pqr

      abc        

    xyz

             def 

    efg
```

then output should be,

```
abc

def

pqr

xyz

efg
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$ awk 'NF && !($1 in a){a[$1];p=$1;print (getline == 0) ? p : p"\n"}' cat
abc

def

pqr

xyz

efg
```

**Explanation**

- `NF && !($1 in a)`: we only process line that is not blank line and the value have not yet appeared in associative array `a`.
- `a[$1]`: if value have not appeared, we save it to associative array `a`.
- `p=$1;print (getline == 0) ? $1 : p"\n"`: we save the value in variable `p`. If not end of file, print variable `p` follow a new line, if end of file, just print `p` value.

Answer (score 2):

This command should work.

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' filename | awk ' !x[$0]++'
```

The first awk command removes all the leading whitespaces in your file and the second awk command just prints unique elements.

Comment: Of course, this only outputs a single blank line when fed with the OP's example data. `cat - | awk '{$1=$1}1' | awk ' !x[$0]++'` Still, it might be close enough.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, yeah. It prints only one blank line and removes the other blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove *all* duplicates (including duplicate empty lines)

```
awk '{if ($1 in a) next; a[$1]=$0; print}' test.txt
```

If you want to retain duplicate empty lines

```
awk '/^$/ {print; next} {if ($1 in a) next; a[$1]=$0; print}' test.txt
```

Comment: Hi Steeldriver, This command works fine. Can you give me command explanation in details?

Answer (score 0):

Example using `unique` command from [`karrick/unique`](https://github.com/karrick/unique):

```
$ cat test.txt | tr -d ' ' | unique
abc

def
pqr
xyz
efg
```